# Update A PostgreSQL Database to Heroku without AWS

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, discord.py

I have a local PostgreSQL Database for my Discord Bot on my PC and want to update to my Heroku Application. I have added the Heroku Postgres Addon, but don't know how to upload the Database. I can't use the Amazon Web Services as told in the  [devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) since i don't have any Credit Card. Is there any way to upload the Database without AWS? Thank You and sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump your local database contents to a SQL file with [pgdump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html). Then you can access your Heroku database from your local machine and upload your SQL using the psql command-line client. [Get the access url](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress) like this from the Heroku command and put it into your client program.

```
heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL
```

Know this: sometimes Heroku migrates your data from one host machine to another. When they do that they change your access url. So retrieve that url again whenever you use the psql client.